# Verificar se dado um valor existem dois valores no vetor que somadas são iguais ao valor informada

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um jogo em que o usuário tem um menu com opções e a opção que eu travei é a seguinte, eu faço o laço normal e comparo os valores mas ele cai direto no `ELSE`, **onde estou errando?**

> 7. Verificar se dado uma pontuação existem duas pontuações na lista de scores que somadas são iguais à
>      pontuação informada.
>      E por fim, temos a operação que verifica se existe no vetor duas pontuações, em posições distintas, que
>      somadas tem como resultado a pontuação informada, o seu programa deve informar sim ou não se existe os a
>      pontuação igual a soma de duas outras pontuações distintas.

O código esta nesse link: [aqui](https://pastebin.com/ygq3u2r1)

```
package scoregamer;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScoreGamer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declara as variaveis
        int codigo = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int qtdVetor = 0;
        int maior= 0;
        int pont = 0;
        int soma = 0;
        int num = 0;
        int posicao = 0;
        int numRemove = 0;
        int add = 0;
        int qtd = 0;
        int tamanho = 5;
        int pontRepetido = 0;
        int totalDeAlunos = 0;
        int verificarPontos = 0;
        int cont = 0;
        int somaPonto = 0;
        int valorNovo = 0;



        //Foi criado o vetor
        int lista[] = new int[10];

        //Utiliza o laço para escolher as opções
        do{
            System.out.println("|-------------------- Menu principal ------------------------|");    
            System.out.println("|                                                            |");
            System.out.println("|(0) Adicionar Pontuação no final da lista                   |");
            System.out.println("|(1) Adicionar Pontuação em uma dada posicção                |");
            System.out.println("|(2) Remover uma pontuação de uma dada posição               |");
            System.out.println("|(3) Remover todas as ocorrências de uma pontuação           |");
            System.out.println("|(4) Verificar se uma pontuação está contida na lista        |");
            System.out.println("|(5) Buscar a maior pontuação na lista de scores             |");
            System.out.println("|(6) Calcular a soma total de pontuação na lista de scores   |");
            System.out.println("|(7) Verificar se dado uma pontuação existem duas pontuações |");
            System.out.println("|(8) Sair                                                    |");
            System.out.println("|------------------------------------------------------------|");  

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Escolha uma opção: ");
            codigo = ler.nextInt();
            //É feito um switch case para escolher uma das opções
            switch(codigo){
                //Adicionar Pontuação no final da lista  
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Digite a pontuação");
                    pont = ler.nextInt();     

                    lista[qtdVetor] = pont;
                    qtdVetor++;
                    imprimeVetor(lista, qtdVetor);
                    break;

                    //Adicionar Pontuação em uma dada posicção 
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Digite a posição que queira adicionar o valor: ");
                    add = ler.nextInt();

                    //Mover todos os elementos
                    qtdVetor++;
                    for(i = qtdVetor-1; i > add; i--){
                        lista[i] = lista[i-1];
                    }
                    System.out.println("Digite o valor para a posição: ");
                    valorNovo = ler.nextInt();
                    lista[i] = valorNovo;

                    imprimeVetor(lista, qtdVetor);                
                    break;

                    //Remover uma pontuação de uma dada posição 
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Digite a posição que queira remover do vetor: ");
                    numRemove = ler.nextInt();

                    //Mover todos os elementos

                    for(i = numRemove; i < qtdVetor-1; i++){
                        lista[i] = lista[i+1];
                    }

                    lista[i] = numRemove;
                    qtdVetor--;
                    imprimeVetor(lista, qtdVetor);    
                break;

                    //Remover todas as ocorrências de uma pontuação 
                case 3:
                    for(i = 0;  i < lista.length; i++){
                        lista[i] = 0;
            }
            imprimeVetor(lista, qtdVetor);
                    break;

                    //Verificar se uma pontuação está contida na lista
                case 4:                        
                    System.out.println("Digite a pontuação");
                    num = ler.nextInt();    
                    for(i = 0; i < qtdVetor; i++){
                        if(lista[i] == num){
                            System.out.println("O numero " +num+ " digitado existe na posição "+i);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                    //Buscar a maior pontuação na lista de scores
                case 5:
                    for(i = 0; i < qtdVetor; i++){
                        if(lista[i] > maior){
                            maior = lista[i];   
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("A maior pontuação foi "+maior);
                    break;

                    //Calcular a soma total de pontuação na lista de scores 
                case 6:                                
                    for(i = 0; i < qtdVetor; i++){
                        soma = soma + lista[i];
                    }
                    System.out.println("Soma total = "+soma);
                    break;

                    //Verificar se dado uma pontuação existem duas pontuações
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("Digite um valor para verificar: ");
                    verificarPontos = ler.nextInt();

                    for(i = 0; i < qtdVetor; i++){   
                        somaPonto += lista[i];    
                    }
                    if(verificarPontos == somaPonto){
                        System.out.println("SIM");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("NAO");
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Você saiu do jogo");
            }
            i++;
        }while(codigo != 8);

    }
    public static void imprimeVetor(int lista[], int qtd){
        System.out.print("{");
        for(int i = 0; i < qtd; i++){
            System.out.print(lista[i]+" ");
        }       
        System.out.println("}");
    }
}
```

Comment: veja se pode ajudar  https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/24AuuS0puY

Answer (score 2):

A cada iteração do ciclo deve definir **somaPonto** como zero. Algo do género:

```
do {
    somaPonto = 0;
    ...
} while(codigo != 8);
```